# How do I limit jQuery Backstretch to homepage only?

Tags: jquery, background, slideshow, blogger

I have added the jQuery function "Backstretch" to my blog, but I only want it to apply to the homepage.
I tried setting each separate page's background to a black image, but the black just fades into the slideshow.

What method would you recommend for limiting the slideshow to the homepage only? (Please bear in mind that I'm just starting out in this code stuff...)

Here is the code:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
/*
* jQuery Backstretch
* Version 1.2.8
* http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/
* Add a dynamically-resized background image to the page
* Copyright (c) 2012 Scott Robbin (srobbin.com)
* Licensed under the MIT license
* https://raw.github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/master/LICENSE.txt
*/
;(function(a){a.backstretch=function(p,b,l){function s(){if(p){var b;0==c.length?c=a("<div />").attr("id","backstretch").css({left:0,top:0,position:m?"fixed":"absolute",overflow:"hidden",zIndex:-999999,margin:0,padding:0,height:"100%",width:"100%"}):c.find("img").addClass("deleteable");b=a("<img />").css({position:"absolute",display:"none",margin:0,padding:0,border:"none",zIndex:-999999,maxWidth:"none"}).bind("load",function(d){var b=a(this),e;b.css({width:"auto",height:"auto"});e=this.width||a(d.target).width();d=this.height||a(d.target).height();n=e/d;q();b.fadeIn(g.speed,function(){c.find(".deleteable").remove();"function"==typeof l&&l()})}).appendTo(c);0==a("body #backstretch").length&&(0===a(window).scrollTop()&&window.scrollTo(0,0),a("body").append(c));c.data("settings",g);b.attr("src",p);a(window).unbind("resize.backstretch").bind("resize.backstretch",function(){"onorientationchange"in window&&window.pageYOffset===0&&window.scrollTo(0,1);q()})}}function q(){try{j={left:0,top:0},rootWidth=h=o.width(),rootHeight=r?window.innerHeight:o.height(),f=h/n,f>=rootHeight?(k=(f-rootHeight)/2,g.centeredY&&(j.top="-"+k+"px")):(f=rootHeight,h=f*n,k=(h-rootWidth)/2,g.centeredX&&(j.left="-"+k+"px")),c.css({width:rootWidth,height:rootHeight}).find("img:not(.deleteable)").css({width:h,height:f}).css(j)}catch(a){}}var t={centeredX:!0,centeredY:!0,speed:0},c=a("#backstretch"),g=c.data("settings")||t;c.data("settings");var o,m,r,n,h,f,k,j;b&&"object"==typeof b&&a.extend(g,b);b&&"function"==typeof b&&(l=b);a(document).ready(function(){var b=window,d=navigator.userAgent,c=navigator.platform,e=d.match(/AppleWebKit\/([0-9]+)/),e=!!e&&e[1],f=d.match(/Fennec\/([0-9]+)/),f=!!f&&f[1],g=d.match(/Opera Mobi\/([0-9]+)/),h=!!g&&g[1],i=d.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)/),i=!!i&&i[1];o=(m=!((-1<c.indexOf("iPhone")||-1<c.indexOf("iPad")||-1<c.indexOf("iPod"))&&e&&534>e||b.operamini&&"[object OperaMini]"==={}.toString.call(b.operamini)||g&&7458>h||-1<d.indexOf("Android")&&e&&533>e||f&&6>f||"palmGetResource"in window&&e&&534>e||-1<d.indexOf("MeeGo")&&-1<d.indexOf("NokiaBrowser/8.5.0")||i&&6>=i))?a(window):a(document);r=m&&window.innerHeight;s()});return this}})(jQuery);
//]]>
</script>

<script>
//<![CDATA[
var images = [
 "https://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5746/30759260720_fcf6549b06_k.jpg",
 "https://c1.staticflickr.com/8/7665/27860820686_c96a964621_k.jpg",
 "https://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5506/30835888326_39d51b9065_k.jpg",
  ];

  $(images).each(function(){
 $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
  });
  var index = 0;
$.backstretch(images[index], {speed: 1000});
  var slideshow = setInterval(function() {
  index = (index >= images.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;
    $.backstretch(images[index]);
  }, 5000);
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us your code, otherwise we dont know what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the jQuery Backstretch plugin code present in your template within the following condition -

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<!-- jQuery Backstretch plugin code -->
</b:if>
```

This condition will only load the code on the homepage.

In your blog, the final code will look like -

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    /*
     * jQuery Backstretch
     * Version 1.2.8
     * http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/
     * Add a dynamically-resized background image to the page
     * Copyright (c) 2012 Scott Robbin (srobbin.com)
     * Licensed under the MIT license
     * https://raw.github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/master/LICENSE.txt
     */
    ;
    (function(a) {
        a.backstretch = function(p, b, l) {
            function s() {
                if(p) {
                    var b;
                    0 == c.length ? c = a("<div />").attr("id", "backstretch").css({
                        left: 0,
                        top: 0,
                        position: m ? "fixed" : "absolute",
                        overflow: "hidden",
                        zIndex: -999999,
                        margin: 0,
                        padding: 0,
                        height: "100%",
                        width: "100%"
                    }) : c.find("img").addClass("deleteable");
                    b = a("<img />").css({
                        position: "absolute",
                        display: "none",
                        margin: 0,
                        padding: 0,
                        border: "none",
                        zIndex: -999999,
                        maxWidth: "none"
                    }).bind("load", function(d) {
                        var b = a(this),
                            e;
                        b.css({
                            width: "auto",
                            height: "auto"
                        });
                        e = this.width || a(d.target).width();
                        d = this.height || a(d.target).height();
                        n = e / d;
                        q();
                        b.fadeIn(g.speed, function() {
                            c.find(".deleteable").remove();
                            "function" == typeof l && l()
                        })
                    }).appendTo(c);
                    0 == a("body #backstretch").length && (0 === a(window).scrollTop() && window.scrollTo(0, 0), a("body").append(c));
                    c.data("settings", g);
                    b.attr("src", p);
                    a(window).unbind("resize.backstretch").bind("resize.backstretch", function() {
                        "onorientationchange" in window && window.pageYOffset === 0 && window.scrollTo(0, 1);
                        q()
                    })
                }
            }

            function q() {
                try {
                    j = {
                        left: 0,
                        top: 0
                    }, rootWidth = h = o.width(), rootHeight = r ? window.innerHeight : o.height(), f = h / n, f >= rootHeight ? (k = (f - rootHeight) / 2, g.centeredY && (j.top = "-" + k + "px")) : (f = rootHeight, h = f * n, k = (h - rootWidth) / 2, g.centeredX && (j.left = "-" + k + "px")), c.css({
                        width: rootWidth,
                        height: rootHeight
                    }).find("img:not(.deleteable)").css({
                        width: h,
                        height: f
                    }).css(j)
                } catch(a) {}
            }
            var t = {
                    centeredX: !0,
                    centeredY: !0,
                    speed: 0
                },
                c = a("#backstretch"),
                g = c.data("settings") || t;
            c.data("settings");
            var o, m, r, n, h, f, k, j;
            b && "object" == typeof b && a.extend(g, b);
            b && "function" == typeof b && (l = b);
            a(document).ready(function() {
                var b = window,
                    d = navigator.userAgent,
                    c = navigator.platform,
                    e = d.match(/AppleWebKit\/([0-9]+)/),
                    e = !!e && e[1],
                    f = d.match(/Fennec\/([0-9]+)/),
                    f = !!f && f[1],
                    g = d.match(/Opera Mobi\/([0-9]+)/),
                    h = !!g && g[1],
                    i = d.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)/),
                    i = !!i && i[1];
                o = (m = !((-1 < c.indexOf("iPhone") || -1 < c.indexOf("iPad") || -1 < c.indexOf("iPod")) && e && 534 > e || b.operamini && "[object OperaMini]" === {}.toString.call(b.operamini) || g && 7458 > h || -1 < d.indexOf("Android") && e && 533 > e || f && 6 > f || "palmGetResource" in window && e && 534 > e || -1 < d.indexOf("MeeGo") && -1 < d.indexOf("NokiaBrowser/8.5.0") || i && 6 >= i)) ? a(window) : a(document);
                r = m && window.innerHeight;
                s()
            });
            return this
        }
    })(jQuery);
    //]]>

</script>
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    var images = [
        "https://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5746/30759260720_fcf6549b06_k.jpg",
        "https://c1.staticflickr.com/8/7665/27860820686_c96a964621_k.jpg",
        "https://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5506/30835888326_39d51b9065_k.jpg",
    ];

    $(images).each(function() {
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
    var index = 0;
    $.backstretch(images[index], {
        speed: 1000
    });
    var slideshow = setInterval(function() {
        index = (index >= images.length - 1) ? 0 : index + 1;
        $.backstretch(images[index]);
    }, 5000);
    //]]>

</script>
</b:if>
```